# Magento Sale order create items grid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I am working in sales order create item grid html file. Where i can find this function `order.itemsUpdate()`? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following js is responsible for admin order

```
js/mage/adminhtml/sales.js
```

Open it and go to

```
itemsUpdate : function(){
    var area = ['sidebar', 'items', 'shipping_method', 'billing_method','totals', 'giftmessage'];
    // prepare additional fields
    var fieldsPrepare = {update_items: 1};
    var info = $('order-items_grid').select('input', 'select', 'textarea');
    for(var i=0; i<info.length; i++){
        if(!info[i].disabled && (info[i].type != 'checkbox' || info[i].checked)) {
            fieldsPrepare[info[i].name] = info[i].getValue();
        }
    }
    fieldsPrepare = Object.extend(fieldsPrepare, this.productConfigureAddFields);
    this.productConfigureSubmit('quote_items', area, fieldsPrepare);
    this.orderItemChanged = false;
},
```

Comment: can you tell me how price update in this grid

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, what you are looking for , check this once :  `dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Mage/Adminhtml/Test/Block/Sales/Order/Create - items.php`

code :

```
 protected $updateProducts = '[onclick="order.itemsUpdate()"]';
```

Comment: seems this is going to get downvotes......

Comment: Thanx for reply Actually i add column item option in this grid as you see dropsown there is some values in drop down e.g 1,2,3 if i change the value and click on update qty then the value of item also update so where i need to make changes